# Ionic-Angularjs | Write logging to file or variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging, ionic-framework, console

I'm working on a new project using Ionic (AngularJs-based) and everything is working as it should be.

I'm currently outputting every 'Function call' (every step) to the console (via a Debug-Function) for debugging purposes so that I can quickly see if every function gets called correctly.

**Log Function (minimised/simplified code):**

```
.factory('DebugMode', ['$log', function($log) {
   var DebugMode = {};
   this.active = true;

   this.console = function(LogLine, LogStyle)}
      if(DebugMode.active){
         $log.log(LogLine);
      }
   };
   return DebugMode;
```

**My question**:
Is there a way or a method that I can also write that output (not specific the console output, but the logs I write to it) to a file or variable?

**My purpose**: Able to request the log when I'm running the app stand-alone and don't have access to a browser or some sort. So that I can easily see if everything is still running correctly or if a client is experiencing some issues, I can ask them to send the Log via mail or some sort.

*For ex. (in the app): Open the menu, go to settings, show log, see where the app returned an error and/or press a button to send that log to me.*

Would the best way be to write everything to a 'log-output.date().txt' sort of thing or store everything in a session variable that gets cleared on exit?

Thanks in advance!

-Bert

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I think [FileLogger](https://github.com/pbakondy/filelogger) would be the best solution and does exactly what I had in mind (more or less).